# rTorrent Config File Script: Prefix Download Path with Hash & Move when Tracker Indicates Zero Leeches

Tags: libtorrent-rasterbar

RE: rTorrent 0.9.2/0.13.2 under Ubuntu 14.04

Two part question, how do I prefix the download path for a torrent added using 'watch' with the hash for the torrent and how do I move and verify that download once complete and after the tracker indicates there are zero leechers?

Why?  The hash prefix is for management of the torrents (currently at 24k and growing.)  The move is from a small 480 GB SSD raid to a 30 TB raid; waiting for the tracker is because the peer connections are dropped when the torrent data is moved or the data is verified.

It's running on a 1,000mbps connection, so the SSD comes in handy during the initial swarm and the 30 TB raid works quite well for seeding (raid 6, so slow for writing.)

I've haven't found any examples for using the hash as a path prefix, but I did find one (here) for moving a completed torrent started from a watch directory, but it also needs to wait for the tracker scrape result of leeches to come back zero.

Up to now I've been running one rTorrent instance per 'new' torrent so I could set the download path prefix to the hash, wait for it to complete, and with an external tracker scrape, wait for zero leeches before stopping the torrent, moving it, and restarting it in one of many 'seeding' rtorrent sessions (file open limit is set at 65000.)

I must be using the wrong search terms as I haven't seen any examples of this in the config file.  Do you think I need to look into using PyroScope or is there a 'direct' solution with just the config file?

Answer (score 0):

```
view_add=archive
system.method.insert=leeches,simple,"not=\"$t.multicall=$d.get_hash=,t.get_scrape_incomplete=\""
view.filter=archive,"and={$d.get_complete=,\"$not=$d.get_peers_connected=\",$leeches=}"
view.sort=archive,5
ui.current_view.set = archive
schedule = sort_archive,14,5,view.sort=archive
```

Here's what I came up with for the selection of completed seeds that are inactive and which the tracker scrape indicates there are no leeches.  Tested using -x.  Any simpler approach or obvious errors?

When I finish the move code and get it all working in the .rtorrent.rc file, I'll post it here for completeness.  Luckily there are many varied examples of moving files around, so that part should be less time consuming.